# send data from activity to its fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm trying to send data from activity to fragment 
here is the activity code :

```
Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putString("username", username);
    ViewEmpAttend fragobj=new ViewEmpAttend();
    fragobj.setArguments(args);
```

here is the fragment code :

```
username=this.getArguments().getString("username");
```

but this code gives me an error said "null object reference" in the onCreateView method in (Fragment Class) .

please help :)

Comment: did you declare your fragment in the layout too?

Comment: please post full code...

Comment: How do you use fragobj? Is it something like that getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragobj).commit(); or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve arguments from onCreate of Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String username = this.getArguments().getString("username"); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In activity define one method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //your code
}
 //define this method
    public String getName(){
        this.name = username;
      }}
```

In fragment use following code.

```
String userName = ((activityName) getActivity()).getName();//you will get name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

For something simple like that, i will just create a constructor method in the fragment to pass in a string.

for example

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

   private String myString;

   public MyFragment (){
     // Recommended Empty Constructor
   }

   public MyFragment (String yourString){
       this.myString = yourString;

   }
}
```

On your Activity class you can pass in the string direct to your fragment constructor

```
public MyClass extends Activity{

   @override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       openFragment();
   }

   public void openFragment(){

       MyFragment fragment = new Fragment("yourString");
       // Here begin the fragment transaction
   }
}
```